# Dbcontext wont autocreate a db

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio-2013

I was watching a pluralsight tutorial and he did the following.
Made some classes, created another with DbContext and when he tried to add a new connection, he could choose this class with DbContext. I do exactly the same, but i'm missing something.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace Thirty3.Models
{
     public class Thirty3Db : DbContext
    {
         public DbSet<Artist> Artists { get; set; }
         public DbSet<Record> Records { get; set; }
         public DbSet<Format> Formats { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Care to point out?

Comment: What version of VS is the Author using, and what version are you using?

Comment: I followed his way, recreating what he did and it worked. Now i'm trying to do it with another project, but i'm missing something. It's not a matter of compatibility.

Comment: I misunderstood, I did not realize it was another project.

Comment: Some probably obvious questions: Have you tried rebuilding and then trying the same thing? Have you closed and reopened visual studio to see if that works?

Answer (score 1):

Try enable AutomaticMigrationsEnabled in Configurations.cs

```
AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
```

Validate your connectionstring and set it to the dbContext-class constuctor.

```
    public Thirty3Db()
        : base("DefaultConnection") // Must match the ConnectionString name in Web.Config
    {
    }
```

Also check that the user you are connecting with is DB_Creator in the SQL Server.